# Is flying a UAV via a VR controller (e.g. Oculus) legal in the US?

Tags: faa-regulations, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I've heard claims that flying a UAV using a Virtual Reality headset (for example, the [oculus rift](https://www.oculus.com/en-us/)) is illegal per FAA regulations.

Is this true? I cannot find any definitive answer either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Model Aircraft Operations](https://www.faa.gov/uas/model_aircraft/) one of the requirements for flying a model aircraft is:

> - Keep the aircraft within visual line of sight at all times

If you are wearing a VR headset, then your *visual line of sight* stops at the headset screen.

Note that the above linked page lists the "visual line of sight" as a safety guideline. However, according to [Section 336](https://www.faa.gov/uas/media/Sec_331_336_UAS.pdf), an aircraft is not considered a "model aircraft" unless it is:

> (2) flown within visual line of sight of the person operating
>   the aircraft

None of the above restricts you from flying with a friend where one of you is wearing the VR headset and the other is piloting the aircraft.